# is there a way to debounce an observer

Tags: ember.js

I have an observer in a controller that saves the object as changes are made. The problem is it is happing too often.

```
changed: ( ->
  #save code goes here 
).observes("description")
```

I am thinking something like http://underscorejs.org/#debounce is needed?

Also It seems to save the object twice once when the attribute changes via a key input and then again when the attribute is set from the returned server value.

Any help would be great I am trying to wrap my head around ember.

Comment: I think the reason that you did not have success with my suggestion is that Ember.debounce /returns a function/ that will run only after debouncing. It doesn't actually run the function by itself. Please have a look at the example I listed in my answer. Let me know how it is different than what you are trying to do. If that's not it, could you perhaps post a jsFiddle that we could use as a base to get the debouncing that you want?

Comment: At least in Ember 1.0.0, Ember.debounce doens't exist anymore. It is Ember.run.debounce which doesn't return a function but adds the function to a lookup hash which gets checked every time the function gets called.

Comment: @Willem the ember-invalid tag is under discussion on meta; http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221611/is-the-ember-invalid-tag-acceptable

Comment: Willem observers are not deprecated. Felix's answer still applies to the current api.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From Ember 1.0.0, you can get a debounced observer in any View or Object by wrapping the debounce call inside another function that observes. `Ember.run.debounce` doesn't return a function but instead adds the function handle to a dictionary. Every subsequent time Ember.run.debounce gets called with that function handle it will check the dictionary to see the last time the function was called and debounce it as expected.

```
var MyView = Ember.View.extend({
    calledRarely: function() {
        console.log("This will log rarely.");
    },

    calledOften: function() {
        console.log("This will log often.");
        Ember.run.debounce(this, this.calledRarely, 1000);
    }.observes("propertyThatChangesOften")
});
```

Here, `this.calledOften` isn't debounced at all so `Ember.run.debounce` will actually be called as often as the property is changed. It won't call `this.calledRarely` until our debounce timeout has completed.

Comment: Yes this is now the way to do it. Ember has come a long way since I asked that question. The upgrade to backburner.js added the much needed dbounce and throttle functions to the run loop.